# What does _("id name") mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

```
<script>
test = _("test");

</script>

<body>
<p id="test"></p>
</body>
```

Here i posted a few lines of code. From this i just want to know _( ) how it works???

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: `_` is a variable referencing a function. `()` calls the function. `"test"` passes a string to that function. It's no different from `my_func("test");`

Comment: This is not plain Javascript, that's for sure.

Comment: @adeneo: In this case, it looks much more like a `document.getElementById` alias.